# Identify groups separated by NA

Tags: r, grouping

I want to add grouping column to my data. My data is text column and there is NA separating groups. Here is example and group is result I would like to achieve. I don't know how many rows each group will consist but there is always NA separating groups (except last group). So how can I create group column?

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(raw = c("This", "Is", "First", NA, "This", "Is", "Second", NA, "And", "Third"),
               group = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the cumulative sum of the NAs and add one if the current value is not NA.

```
data %>% mutate(group = cumsum(is.na(raw)) + !is.na(raw))
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a logical vector based on the `NA` value and use `cumsum`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
      mutate(groupNew = cumsum(lag(is.na(raw), default = TRUE)) )
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   raw    group groupNew
#   <chr>  <dbl>    <int>
# 1 This       1        1
# 2 Is         1        1
# 3 First      1        1
# 4 <NA>       1        1
# 5 This       2        2
# 6 Is         2        2
# 7 Second     2        2
# 8 <NA>       2        2
# 9 And        3        3
#10 Third      3        3
```